# How to add a padding which stays platform responsive according to screens?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Media query does not help in the `EdgeInsets.only()` case or maybe the case I did not understand. I used padding: `EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/10)`, but it not helping in "only" case.

```
    Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 160, left: 90, bottom: 20),
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          'assets/logo.png',
          height: 70,
          width: 70,
        ),
        Text(
          '  Whatsapp',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 26,
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: You can use MediaQuery however it would need to be each one. So for example:

`padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 160, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/10, bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/10)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a package that you can use

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil

Add the dependency to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
flutter_screenutil: <latest version>
```

Initialize the package in the build method with screen height and width. You can get that from MediaQuery.

```
final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
ScreenUtil.init(context,
              width: size.width,
              height: size.height,
              allowFontScaling: false);
```

Now you can proceed to append .w and .h to padding values. ".w" returns a fraction of what ever value it's appended to relative to the screen's width. ".h" does the same but with screen's height.

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 160.h, left: 90.w, bottom: 20.h),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'assets/logo.png',
              height: 70,
              width: 70,
            ),
            Text(
              '  Whatsapp',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```